# Change Image of Imageview onItemClickListener of ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I am using Custom `ListView` to show image and text and that is using `Cursor`. Now, `onItemClickListener()`, I want to change Image of `ImageView` and I also want to change textColor of `TextView`. And I want to disable that Item from click on which user `Click`. I have tried several things but none of them worked.
How to do this ?

**XML Code:**

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/queimg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_answer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/option"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:text="hello" />
```

**Java Code :**

```
        final List<String> lstOption = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> arrlist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        Map<String, String> m = null;
        if (option != null) {
            if (option.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    lstOption.add(option.getString(option
                            .getColumnIndex("Option")));

                    m = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    m.put("option",
                            option.getString(option.getColumnIndex("Option")));

                    arrlist.add(m);
                } while (option.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist,
                R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" },
                new int[] { R.id.option });


lvTWOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
lvTWOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selection[position] = true;
    ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageResourceId);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.option)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Try this code, hope it will help.

```
final boolean[] selection = new boolean[arrlist.length];
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist, R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" },new int[] { R.id.option }){
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return !(selection[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is simplest way to do it. Thank you so much. You save my time.

Comment: check updated post. one more question. I want to disable Item Click.

Comment: You want to block the user from selecting it ?

Comment: Make it a class variable

Comment: can u tell me in details, i am new so nt getting proper idea ?

Comment: define it on top of your adapter initialization

Comment: sorry, by mistake i clicked on it. and i tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achive that is to extend the `BaseAdaptor` class and use a custom item in list.